# Xbox live gamertag recovery

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

How do recover a gamertag, on Xbox live? But I know longer know the email address or the password associated with the account

Answer (score 1):

You will need to personally [contact Microsoft's Xbox Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us#3:0:4). they give you a couple of options, from email contact to phone support.

The more proof you have that you are the original owner of the account, the better. Here are some things you can have at the ready to give them more confidence, and hopefully sort your problem out quicker:

- Any personal details you signed up to the account with (an old address, phone number or email address)
- Any credit card you have linked to the account (they will only need the last four numbers, in effort to keep your cards secure)
- Any key you redeemed (eg. games you purchased as an Xbox key, DLC redemption codes you might have received with physical games)
- A rough history of your account use (anybody can check if an account has played a copy of Batman: Arkham Asylum, for example, but the owner is more likely to be the only one that knows the game was played for a couple of months half a year after its release, and never again, since.)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to talk to Microsoft Support for XBox Live.. That is pretty much your only option at this point in time.